# Is there a difference between Macro Average and Weighted Average in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, evaluation

I was testing some algorithms on a few different data-sets relating to network intrusion detection and in the classification reports generated I often see something called a'macro average' and a 'weighted average (See image below).
[image: Example: SVM classification results: macro and weighted average]
Could someone explain what they are and their differences (if any) in simple terms?

Answer (score 4):

Macro average gives each prediction similar weight while calculating loss but there might be case when your data might be imbalanced and you want to give importance to some prediction more (based on their proportion), there you use 'weighted' average.